# What does it mean being one-to-one

Tags: calculus, functions

On which interval [a,b] will the function:

$$
f(x)= \frac{x-1}{x^2 + 1}
$$ be one-to-one?

What does it mean being one to one?

Comment: It just means that there are no two distinct values $x_1,x_2 \in [a,b]$ that satisfy $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$.

Comment: That was a rather thoughtless answer, sorry. I've deleted it.

Comment: @HandeBruijn how can i explain it?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

One-to-one means that not only there is *one* value of $y$ belonging to $x$ (as is commonly the case if $y$ is a function of $x$) but also the reverse: there is only *one* value of $x$ belonging to $y$. Can you see in the above picture where this might be the case? And how $a$ and $b$ can be determined then?

P.S. Replaces a deleted answer.

Comment: That's a strange way to define one-to-one!

Comment: in fact, the equation $x=g(y)$ has only one solution

Comment: @Han de Bruijn is that all? shouldnt we give exact interval?